# Из-за альтернативного IP пропадает часть компов

Tags: сеть, ip, lan

Всем привет!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема, добавляю альтернативный IP адрес (192.168.1.201) для просмотра другой подсети и у меня пропадают половина компов в обозревателе сети из 15-ой подсети?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заметил, что в IPCONFIG альтернативный IP-адрес 1.201 - почему-то - ОСНОВНОЙ, и если проверить таблицу маршрутов (route print), то видно, что комп 15.201 ходит через 1.201.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сделать 15.201 - ОСНОВНЫМ? Или что можно сделать, чтобы при прописывании альтернативного IP не пропадали компы в обозревателе? Без переназначения маски или подсети.

Метрику пробовал ставить в ручную "1", при первом "route print" идет через 15-ую подсеть, при втором уже через первую. Пробовал в реестр добавлять «IPAutoconfigurationEnabled» не помогло.
Как только убираю 1-ую подсеть, в обозревателе появляются все компы.

Comment: Что поделаешь. Так работает netbios, протокол используемый для просмотра сети. Он привязывается только к одному адресу на физический интерфейс. Не знаю поможет ли в данной ситуации даже установка сервера WINS. Надо переходить на современные протоколы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А что вы имеете ввиду под современные протоколы?

Comment: Active Directory

Comment: Так настроен он. Я даже не представляю сеть без AD, сколько это головняков будет )                                                                                     А как быть в такой ситуации с исчезновение компов с AD? Что можно придумать, чтобы такого не было?

Comment: Про ad наврал. Кажется всё новое пришло вместе с ad, что вообще, говоря, неверно не так. Есть в виндовсе какие-то новые службы для исследования сети, кроме старого netbios. netbios раньше хорошо знал, а новые и не изучал. Может Вам просто вторую сетевую карту установить? Вот здесь https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940063.aspx есть раздел `NetBIOS Name Registration and Resolution for Multihomed Computers`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Буду разбираться.